# Remove xml tag while creating web service in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, json

I am creating a webservice in asp.net. Below is the response I'm getting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">{"Question1":"do the like the idea of the first speaker?","Option1":"YES","Option2":"NO","Option3":"NOT SURE","Option4":"","Option5":"","Type":"button","QID":"q1"}</string>
```

How can I remove the xml tag from here...any ideas?

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetQuestions()
{
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Biz.BAL.GetQuestions());
}
```

Comment: How are you getting the above response? Note that if you test the webservice through your webbrowser you will get a different result than when you do an actuall ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you verify you web.config if the following is correct:

1) "Rerouting the *.ASMX httphandler to ScriptHandlerFactory"

```
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove path="*.asmx" verb="*"/>
        <add path="*.asmx" verb="*" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpHandlers>
```

2) "Json serialization"
 You can add the jsonSerialisation setting to your web.config to make sure the Json serialization works:

```
    <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
            <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/></sectionGroup></sectionGroup></sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
```

Comment: other thought... did you already add the attribute [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] to your webservice ? (presumably yes since you already call a ScriptMethod.. )

Comment: Final thought = rerouting asmx httphandler.. I've edited my answer for that. If that does not help you, I'm clueless, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Please use these lines in Web Method:

---

```
 JavaScriptSerializer Machinejson = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            this.Context.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            this.Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"; // to remove xml tag from response
            this.Context.Response.Write(Machinejson.Serialize([Object or string to return in form of json)]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this code is safe and convinient:
ASP

```
var X = new XmlDocument();
X.LoadXml(YOUR_RESPONSE);
return X.DocumentElement.InnerText;
```

in Javascript I think you should do somthing like this

```
var start = YOUR_RESPONSE.indexOf('<string ');
start = YOUR_RESPONSE.indexOf('>', start)+ 1;
YOUR_RESPONSE.substring(start, YOUR_RESPONSE.lastIndexOf('</string>'));
```

Comment: XmlDocument x= new XmlDocument();
x.LoadXml(new javaScriptSerializer(). Serialize(Biz.BAL.GetQuestions().ToString()));
return x.DocumentElement.InnerText;

Comment: above asp code is not working...its throwing xml exception Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Comment: I have tested this right now with your example and it's work. What happended exactly? Did Compilation error occure or run time exception?

Comment: Please debug your code and check if your data had an invalid character?

Comment: And in JS alert data before each line to debug them.

Comment: thanks for the reply...your js code is working fine but when i try to use ur asp code..it didn;t work...
x.LoadXml(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Biz.BAL.GetQuestions().ToString())); This is giving xmlexception "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1"

Comment: If your data is exacly the same as you posted, i had checked it, it works. So please check your data in debug mode. Check Quick Watch on this "new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Biz.BAL.GetQuestions().ToString())"